# passing argument to JavaScript function for submit forms

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I need to make a simple form submit by JavaScript confirm dialog. 
The submit goes to delete an item in the database, so I want to ask confirmation message by printing information about the element to be deleted.

The form code is:

```
echo "<form action='manage_cycles.php' method='POST' onsubmit='return conferma($(this))' name='form_form'>";
   echo "<input type='hidden' name='cycle_id' value='".$cycle['cycleID']."'>";
   echo "<td style='width:40px;'><button type='submit' name='delete_cycle' value='".$cycle['cycleName']."' style='color:blue;font-size:12px'>Delete</button></td>";
echo "</form>";
```

The information i'm trying to print in the confirm dialog is the value of the button tag, $cycle['cycle_name'].

The code of the JavaScript function is:

```
function conferma(element){

    var button_value = element.find("button").attr("value");

    var msg = "Are you sure you want to delete " + button_value + "?";

    return confirm(msg);
  }
```

The confirm dialog  message is:

> Are you sure you want to delete Undefined?

Then the return value works properly and submit or not the form by clicking Y/N option.

I didn't understand where I'm wrong

Comment: `return conferma(this)` instead return `conferma($(this))` and wrap `element` with `$(element)` to make `.find()` work!

Comment: tried with return conferma(this) and wrapping element with $(element)...doesn't work (I think i tried all combination for passing argument and wrap element)

Comment: did you try `element.find("button").val()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this "coglione"

```
echo "<form action='manage_cycles.php' method='POST' onsubmit='return confirm(\"Are you sure you want to delete \" + this.delete_cycle.value + \"?\");' name='form_form'>";
       echo "<input type='hidden' name='cycle_id' value='".$cycle['cycleID']."'>";
       echo "<td style='width:40px;'><button type='submit' name='delete_cycle' value='".$cycle['cycleName']."' style='color:blue;font-size:12px'>Delete</button></td>";
    echo "</form>";
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may answer the question, it would be better if you could add some explanation as to how and why it answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
conferma(this)
```

instead of

```
conferma($(this))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, try this:

```
$('[name=form_form]').submit(function() {
    var btn_val = $(this).find('button').attr('value');
    return confirm("Are you sure, you want to delete " + btn_val + "?");
});
```

and omit the `onsubmit`-attribute on your `form`-tag.

Comment: i tried something similar(submitting form with js launching function by press button that was type ="button" otherwise "submit"), but I do not know why then the variable $_POST['delete_cycle'] is not set, so I can't control via PHP for actually delete from the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Almost there, try this way:

Form element:

```
onsubmit='return conferma(this)'
```

Function:

```
function conferma(element){

    var button_value = $(element).find("button").attr("value");

    var msg = "Are you sure you want to delete " + button_value + "?";

    return confirm(msg);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

call this method

```
function conferma(){

    var button_value = $("button[name='delete_cycle']").val();
    return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete " + button_value + "?");

}
```